# Custom paypal form without paypal button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

How can i create a custom form of Paypal in react with fields of email/cardNumber/expiry Date/CVC? I am familiar with paypal buttons but using this will redirect users to paypal login also this form can be done easily with stripe.Any guide on Paypal ?

Thanks